# How to visualize an sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I've trained a [gradient boost classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier), and I would like to visualize it using the graphviz_exporter tool shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).

When I try it I get:

```
AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

this is because the graphviz_exporter is meant for [decision trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier), but I guess there's still a way to visualize it, since the gradient boost classifier must have an underlying decision tree.

How to do that?

Comment: have you tried to use XGBoost  [link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/)?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the XGBoost library. I'll give it a check, although I found how to do it using sklearn

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The attribute estimators contains the underlying decision trees. The following code displays one of the trees of a trained GradientBoostingClassifier. Notice that although the ensemble is a classifier as a whole, each individual tree computes floating point values.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import numpy as np

# Ficticuous data
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(1000, 3))
y = X[:,0]+X[:,1]*X[:,2] > 0

# Classifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X[:600], y[:600])

# Get the tree number 42
sub_tree_42 = clf.estimators_[42, 0]

# Visualization
# Install graphviz: https://www.graphviz.org/download/
from pydotplus import graph_from_dot_data
from IPython.display import Image
dot_data = export_graphviz(
    sub_tree_42,
    out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,
    special_characters=True,
    proportion=False, impurity=False, # enable them if you want
)
graph = graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
png = graph.create_png()
# Save (optional)
from pathlib import Path
Path('./out.png').write_bytes(png)
# Display
Image(png)
```

Tree number 42:

[image: Code output (decision tree image)]

Comment: Yes, but in this case, you have 200 estimators. So its not practical or useful to print out 200 trees to understand it. [See this](https://arogozhnikov.github.io/2016/06/24/gradient_boosting_explained.html) for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, that page is really useful for me to understand the whole concept better

Comment: Can you add the dependencies to run the answer?

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia Done. I also added the image output.

Comment: getting the error `InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found` when executing this example.

Comment: @SatyamAnand You need to install `graphviz` in your system: https://www.graphviz.org/download/

Comment: Hello guys! how can I keep my default variable names when I draw tree as above?@CarlosPinzón @VivekKumar

Comment: @VivekKumar Use `feature_names=["size", "cost", "speed", ...]`. Check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) for seeing all available settings.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón Thank you for your answer. How could we save this image?

Comment: @HoseinBasafa thanks. I added the instructions for saving the image to a file.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing answer, there is another nice visualization package called `dtreeviz` which I find really useful.

Borrowing code from the existing answer:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import numpy as np
from dtreeviz.trees import *

# Ficticuous data
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(1000, 3))
y = X[:,0]+X[:,1]*X[:,2] > 0

# Classifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X[:600], y[:600])

# Get the tree number 42
sub_tree_42 = clf.estimators_[42, 0]

# Visualization
viz = dtreeviz(sub_tree_42,
               x_data=X,
               y_data=y,
               target_name='Positive',
               feature_names=['X0', 'X1', 'X2'],
               class_names=['Negative', 'Positive'],
               title='Tree 42 visualization')

viz.save("tree_visualization.svg") 
viz.view()
```

[image]